# Convertir un string a Date de datepicker Materialize

Tags: php, mysql, materialize

tardes , noches, vale la pena recalcar que soy nuevo en php por lo cual he intentado algunas cosas de java pero claramente no todo funciona, me gustaría saber como convertir un string que me entrega datepicker de Materialize a un date para poder entregárselo a mi base de datos MySQL, me gustaría agradecer de antemano por su ayuda

Comment: [mktime](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mktime.php) revisa el manual con las funciones de Tiempo

Answer (score 0):

En php existe una función llamada date

Date("yyyy-mm-dd", strtotime($fechadeinput) )

Yyyy-mm-dd es el formato que usa mysql año mes y día en ese orden